# Right way to implement tabs in Vue - dependent parent-child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a tabs component.
My tabs layout:

```
<tabs>
   <tab-link to="tab1">Tab1</tab-link>
   <tab-link to="tab2">Tab2</tab-link>

   <tab-pane name="tab1">content</tab-pane>
   <tab-pane name="tab2">content</tab-pane>
</tabs>
```

(Very similar to what is done in Vuetify.)

In Vue, how does one implement this kind of component structure?
In React, there is `React.children.map()` function, so the parent component can inspect its children and make rendering decisions based on the child type.

Some pattern I thought of:
A `<tab-link>` get clicked, and `$emit` event which is caught by `<tabs>`.
Now, `<tabs>` component need to find the appropriate `<tab-pane>` and make it visible. How can the `<tabs>` component do that?

Maybe another pattern?

Comment: Start with looking the built-in `<component :is="ComponentName"` of vue.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: I read it, what I'm not sure about is how should I analyze the content I get inside the <tabs> component to match tab-item and its content and to add <tabs-slider> component?

Comment: Basically you would want to have two components. One that handles the switching.
Another one which renders the child.
The content (includes slider) will go inside the relevant child.

Comment: My idea is <tabs> container that hold the active tab with the actual dom element so the slider can be positioned appropriately. the <tabs-slider> should get inside the <tabs> I think. 
But how to I parse what I get in the default slot in <tabs>, let's say I get something like 
`<tabs> <tab-item> ... </tab-item> <tab-content></tab-content>...<tab-slider/></tabs>`

Comment: Can you add some working code for your implementation.
Just the barebones, so that we can help you better.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Updated the question, I think it's clear now.